# Center multi-line legend title

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I would like to *fully* center my multi-line legend title.

When the title spans one line, it's centered. When it spans multiple lines, it seems like the longest line gets centered, then all other lines are left-aligned with respect to that longest line.

I've looked into the `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` class, which is where I saw that I could bold the title but there does not seem to be any option for centering. Appreciate any advice!

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 5], label='Very Long label A')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 4, 1], label='Very Long label B')

leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_title('Legendary\nTitle', prop={'size': 12, 'weight':'bold'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to using `TeX` is to set the `multialignment` parameter of the legend title. I don't see a way to set that as you create it, but since it is just a matplotlib `Text` object, we can do that after setting the title using the [`.set_multialignment()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_multialignment) function, like so:

```
leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_title('Legendary\nTitle', prop={'size': 12, 'weight':'bold'})
leg.get_title().set_multialignment('center')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My go-to solution is to use the Tex capabilities of matplotlib. You can find a tutorial and the requirements [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/usetex.html).
With the below code the legend title becomes centered.

Of course, now you could make full use of Tex formatting and do not have to fall back to font properties. I have included this for the sake of demonstration showing that you can mix it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2, 5], label='Very Long label A')
ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 4, 1], label='Very Long label B')

leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_title(r'\begin{center} Legendary \\ Title \end{center}', prop={'size': 12, 'weight':'bold'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for pointing me to Tex! That does open up many possibilities. I'll check later if it works and will mark as accepted if so.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! I've however decided to mark @tmdavison's answer as accepted as it works more cleanly and will probably work for more people since text.usetex does have some external dependencies that not everyone can easily get fulfilled